# How many times can I solder/desolder a through-hole component on a PCB?

Tags: pcb, soldering, temperature

I am very new to soldering and desoldering and want to try doing it on a mouse's switches. I want to try out multiple different types of switches on the same mouse. I read that the temperature limit for PCBs is 100C or 150C. But how many times can I desolder and solder new switches on before I damage the PCB due to temperature problems?

Comment: what you read is incorrect, PCBs can typically withstand much higher temperatures, otherwise the manufacturer of your mouse couldn't have soldered things onto it. The problem, realistically, is that as a beginner, you will not be able to control your soldering temperature very well when unsoldering a relatively large component like a switch, so you are very likely to overheat your PCB. We can't tell you how many times you can do that before it fails. Don't you have something else to train on than a device that you still care about?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I will try practicing on other items first. Would it be dangerous if I only resolder it twice (after factory solder) and to it really quickly (1-2 seconds per pin) with only 3 pins to do?

Comment: I know neither your board, nor your switch, nor your iron, nor how good your method of soldering is. That question has no honest answer.

Comment: The pads (round copper rings) are held to the PCB with a glue that  intentionally melts at a temperature below that of solder.  This avoids mechanical stresses that may occur as it cools and things shrink.   Too many attempts at soldering/desoldering the board will burn up the glue and the pads don't stick anymore.   How many times depends on how good ( how fast) you are.  I could probably do it 4 or 5x more than you, but I've been soldering for 40 years.   Best thing...find scrap boards and practice!

Comment: How many mouses can you afford if it goes badly wrong? Badly wrong would usually mean the traces coming off the PCB, which can be achieved by overheating and also by removing the component when not all the solder has been removed. Do you have a temperature-controlled soldering iron? Also, the mouse shell might wear out from repeated disassembly before there's any other damage - remember to turn the screws backwards until they click into the thread in the plastic (the deepest click) before doing them up to avoid damaging the hole.

Comment: @strangeronthestreet Try finding and buying something that looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPs0w.png). It's a PCB with PTH (plated through holes.) You can practice to your heart's content on these. There are some poorer quality ones. But a good one will look approximately like that.

Comment: @kyle source? Cause damn that makes too much sense. TIL.

Comment: I think a cheap soldering iron has no temperature control so it gets WAY TOO HOT and incinerates things the first time. My termperture controlled soldering iron was not too expensive for its many years being used and has never incinerated anything.

Comment: there may be other way to accomplish what you are trying to do ... please add pictures of the mouse PCB

Comment: @Passerby  Oh man I wish I could tell you that.  I've been in so many PCB assembly houses and designed so many PCBA's, I have no idea where I picked up certain pieces of info (like that one).   So I guess, take with a grain of salt and YMMV   ;)

Comment: The quality of the PCB is what matters the most by far. Series production PCBs usually don't handle desoldering very well, as opposed to higher quality prototype PCBs. However, this is mostly related to SMD pads leaving the board, through-hole plated vias are far more rugged.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple components that you have to keep in mind.

The actual pcb substrate. The plated through hole via you are soldering to. The trace leading away from the hole. The quality, condition, and temperature of your iron and the quality and condition of the solder. The lead on the part. The plastic on the part. Any other parts near where you are soldering. Technique.

There is no fixed number or even simple calculation for what you are asking. Most parts are not designed to be soldered on and off repeatedly. It's often a one and done and that's all the manufacturer will test. Some pcbs will self destruct if you look at them wrong. Some are built like tanks.

The number of times is 1 to infinity if you are really good. Sometimes it's 0 because you fail to solder to it even once. Or 0.5 for failing to desolder from it once.

If you want to remove parts often you use connectors or sockets.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the tools you have on hand and your proficiency. If you're a beginner, you may have zero or 1 attempt.

If you have a desoldering station, perhaps 5 to 10 times with an experienced operator. With large parts or ground plane attachment, a preheater for the PCB; along with a proper desoldering station; reduces the risk of board damage. Using a desoldering station requires proper technique and practice. Desoldering stations also require proper upkeep (cleaning the tip barrel after every session).

[image: Hakko FR410-52]
Vacuum desoldering station.

If you're depending on a hand-held solder sucker like an Edsyn SS750LS (my favorite due to the low mass of the plunger which means less recoil), or equivalent, 2 or 3 times if your skills are good and are lucky. However, I don't recommend using a solder sucker on a part with a rigid body as you're likely to damage the PCB due to multiple attempts to clear the solder from the hole.

[image: Edsyn SS750LS]
Hand-held solder sucker.

Desoldering braid is another technique. For a rigid body part, I would not recommend this method.

[image]
Desoldering braid.

If the switch pins are close enough, you can bridge the pins with a heavy piece of copper wire (#18 to #14 AWG, 1.0 to 1.6mm dia) and heat all the pins at once. You'll need a soldering iron tip with sufficient mass (on the larger side) to use this method. If you have bismuth solder, you can use this to lower the melting temperature of the joints by contaminating the existing solder joint with bismuth. Contaminating the joint with bismuth is helpful regardless of which technique you use. I will give this technique 5 times with an experienced technician.

If you have multiple soldering irons, use two people. One to hold the soldering irons, one to hold the board and remove the part. I will give this technique 5 to 10 times.

On the temperature limit for the PCB, that is probably the operational temperature of the PCB. Reflow soldering requires a temperature range of 240 to 250°C which the PCB is built to briefly withstand.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments there are quite some unknowns. From my experience, parts will die in this order (easiest to least likely):

- mechanical components such as buttons or connectors with plastic cases
- narrow PCB traces or annular rings (delamination), especially for cheap PCBs
- large ceramic capacitors in SMD packages (heat expansion cracking)
- everything else is very tough

I have replaced some SMD components more than 10 times without destroying anything and I have destroyed other PCBs in the first attempt when trying to remove a many-pin through-hole connector. So these are your bounding values: 0 .. >10 times.

Answer (score 0):

The first time is the most critical. If you can unsolder it once without damaging the board then you should be able to do it many more times.

Single-sided boards are easier to work on than multilayer boards because you don't have to suck solder out of plated through holes. However they are easier to damage because the pads are held down only by the glue under them.

Most manufacturers today use lead-free solder, which has a high melting point. To lower the required working temperature you can *add* a lower temperature solder to the joints before unsoldering the component. This helps transfer heat to the original solder and lowers the combined melting point.

In most cases using standard 60/40 Pb/Sn solder (188 °C melting temperature) or 63/37 'eutectic' solder (183 °C) will do the job. For particularly sensitive boards and/or components you can use an even lower temperature solder such as 42/58 tin-bismuth (138 °C) or In97/Ag3 (eg. [Chip Quik](http://www.chipquik.com/store/product_info.php?products_id=210001) which melts at 58 °C).

If you use low temperature solder to solder the component back in then it will be much easier to remove again. For testing you only need to solder enough pins to work. Usually only 2 pins of a microswitch or tactile switch need to be connected, or you might even get away with bending pins to make a tight connection without solder!

Comment: Note that using a low-melting-point solder to help desolder will probably leave behind a bit of bismuth or indium that will alloy with whatever solder you use next, if you solder something else onto the same pads. I'm not sure what effect this will have, but probably not much. Some may also be left behind on your soldering iron tip; just clean it well and re-tin it with fresh solder of whatever type you plan to use. Maybe a couple cycles of cleaning and re-tinning.

Answer (score -1):

The temperature limit does not depend on the PCB, rather it depends on the components mounted on the PCB. Each component can withstand different temperature (mentinoed specifically in their datasheets). As long as you don't melt nearby PCB tracks or damage the other component by excessive heat, you can resolder the components multiple times.

Comment: "The temperature limit does not depend on the PCB" That is certainly not true. You can easily damage a PCB with too much heat.

Comment: What *is* true is that a mechanical + plastic component like a mouse microswitch is indeed very sensitive to overheating itself.

Comment: not convinced about the "infinite times", either.

Comment: I highly doubt that the PCB can withstand infinite number of desoldering and soldering cycles. Especially if done with no prior experience.

Comment: @marcus while statistically unlikely it's not mathematically impossible for it to be infinitely.

Comment: @Noman have you never melted a pcb or even delaminated it? Heat is a pcb killer.